# Problema overlay @media

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou com dificuldades de entender uma coisa. Eu estou montando um questionário e quando a pessoa não seleciona nenhuma alternativa aparece uma *box* com *overlay* dizendo que é para ela selecionar.

Código CSS:

```css
.backdrop{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:1020px;
    background:#000;
    opacity: .0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index:50;
    display:none;
}

.box{
    position:fixed;
    top:200px;
    left:700px;
    width:470px;
    height:250px;
    background:#3093C7;
    display:block;
    z-index:51;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
    display:none;
}

.close{
    float:right;
    margin-right:6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Código jQuery:

```js
function overK(){
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
}

$('.backdrop').click(function(){
    close_box();    
});

$('.close').click(function(){
    close_box();
});

function close_box(){
    $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function() {
        $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
    });
}
```

### Problema:

Quando eu utilizo `@media` para arrumar outros elementos da página caso a resolução seja menor, ele não aceita as novas propiedades da `.box` e `.backdrop`.

Por que isso acontece?

```css
@media (max-width:1700px) and (min-width: 1600px) {

    .box{
        position:fixed;
        top:200px;
        left:100px;
        width:470px;
        height:250px;
        background:#3F0;
        display:block;
        z-index:51;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
        display:none;
    }

    .divbuttons{
        display:inline;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        left:510px;     
    }

    .containerText{
        background-color:#090;
        width:95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você já tentou substituir `@media (max-width:1700px) and (min-width: 1600px) {` por `@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) and (min-width: 1600px) {`?

Comment: Já cara, eu fiz vários testes aqui e pelo que eu entendi o problema é que o css ta pegando na classe principal, e não no da media, não sei se fui claro.

Comment: por exemplo, quando eu edeletei as classes e só deixei na media ele funcionou, parece que não ta achando as classes dentro do media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem ver os outros @media queries presentes na página fica dificil, mas de fato, um media query vai substituir o outro caso eles se cruzem. Ou se por exemplo você tiver a mesma classe declarada fora dos media queries.

Nesse caso, você tem três opções:

1. Arrumar os media queries e garantir que não se sobreponham
2. Usar !important nas classes que estão dentro do media query (não
   recomendado)
   **ex:** top:200px !important;
3. Caso este seja o único media query presente na página e você quer
   que ele substitua declarações gerias do código, faça esta classe
   mais especifica. **Ex:** *Classe geral:* .box{ }  *Classe no media query:* body .box{ } ou .parentDiv .box{ }

A terceira opção é a mais indicada, a classe mais especifica será considerada.